# how to get Video from Server source C#

Tags: c#, video

How can i download the video from server source through C#?

this is the video
www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZS0eX8Fe7U&feature=fvhl

and this is the server source of this video
http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/watch_as3-vflPDfEzH.swf

I apply same procedure for images and easily download from server

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebClient to download pages:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://foo.com/somefile", @"c:\somefile");
}
```

Also notice that what you've provided is not the address of the video file. It is the address of the player. AFAIK the policy forbids downloading the video files from youtube but if you have the address of the video file simply pass it to the [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) method.

Comment: can you make this code from this urlwww.youtube.com/watch?v=UZS0eX8Fe7U&feature=fvhl

Comment: System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            byte[] bytedata = client.DownloadData("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZS0eX8Fe7U&feature=fvhl");
            client.DownloadFile("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZS0eX8Fe7U&feature=fvhl", @"c:\A");

Comment: this get an error An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a youtube video file, its a youtube video player. Video is returned by /get_video? ...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download *that* movie get something like DownloadHelper for FireFox. If you are trying to download *any movie* from youtube then use code like Darin suggeseted.